# boost input stream error. how to save dynamic vector of std:vectors as xml file

Tags: c++, xml, serialization, boost, stdvector

I am trying to save a

```
vector<vector<int>>
```

as an xml file. 
the vectors will be dynamically resizable .
I tried using BOOST:SERIALIZATION
but I receive this error.
 **libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::archive::archive_exception: input stream error**

I can't see any problems with my code. 
Another method other than boost to save as an xml would be fine with me if someone can suggest one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    using namespace std;
    int numChords;

    vector<vector<int> > chords; // array to store chord arrays
    numChords = 2; // size of outer array
    chords = {{41, 48, 55, 56, 58, 63},
              {44, 51, 56, 58, 61, 63}}; // data structure

    // print the array
    cout << endl << "you entered: " << endl;
    // print the results
    for (int i = 0; i < numChords; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < chords[i].size(); j++) {
            cout << chords[i][j] << ",";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    // store the array to a file
    std::ofstream ofs("dump.dat");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa & chords;

    chords.clear(); // clear the original array
    // restore the array from the file
    std::ifstream ifs("dump.dat");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
    ia & chords;

    cout << endl << "you saved: " << endl;
    // print the restored array
    for (int i = 0; i < numChords; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < chords[i].size(); j++) {
            cout << chords[i][j] << ",";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried various different filenames and filepaths. I tried using & or << >> after the boost statement.

Full output is

```
you entered: 
41,48,55,56,58,63,
44,51,56,58,61,63,
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::archive::archive_exception: input stream error

Process finished with exit code 6
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose output and input operations on stream by braces:

```
{ //<--
  // store the array to a file
  std::ofstream ofs("dump.dat");
  boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
  oa & chords;
}

chords.clear(); // clear the original array

{ // <--
  // restore the array from the file
  std::ifstream ifs("dump.dat");
  boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
  ia & chords;
}
```

[Here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/serialization/doc/exceptions.html) is reference about exceptions which are thrown  by *boost::archive*. 
Below sentence regards to `input/output stream error`:

> Be sure that an output archive on a stream is destroyed before opening
>   an input archive on that same stream.

If this condition is not fulfilled, you get exception.